# How to print/dump NSObject?

Tags: swift, console, nsobject

I have a

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setObjectValue(loginAccount, forKey: "loginAccount")
```

[image]

I have access to `SwiftyJSON` Pod in my project, so I've tried

```
print(JSON(loginAccount))
```

I got

```
unknown
```

What should I do to make my dict more humanly readable ?

---

## SessionAccount

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON


public class SessionAccount : NSObject {

    var id             : Int?
    var username       : String?
    var password       : String?
    var accountType    : String?
    var role           : String?
    var privateVlan    : String?
    var guestVlan      : String?
    var timezoneOffset : Int?
    var loginTime      : Date?
    var cpe            : CPE?
    var cpeName        : String?
    var cpeProfiles    : [Profile] = []
    var deviceCount    : Int?
    var activeCount    : Int?
    var inactiveCount  : Int?
    var offlineCount   : Int?
    var profileDevices : [Device] = []
    var cpeDevices     : [Device] = []
    var lanSetting     : LANSetting?
    var alerts         : [Alert] = []
    var quarantineList : [String] = []

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(_ record: JSON) {
        self.init()
        self.id = record["id"].int
        self.accountType = record["accountType"].string
        self.role = record["role"].string
        self.timezoneOffset = record["timezoneOffset"].int
    }

}
```

Comment: Only use Swift version specific tags if your question is about a specific change in that version of the language. Your question is clearly not concerned about a specific change, so don't use those tags to show which version you are using. The assumption is always the latest version.

Comment: What is `SessionAccount` ?

Comment: @Koen : I updated my post, and here also : https://i.imgur.com/YWVU9qU.png

Comment: Your question is very confusing. The title is not reflected at all in the body. If you want to "make my dict more humanly readable", you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773979/is-there-a-way-to-pretty-print-swift-dictionaries-to-the-console

Comment: I want to make pretty print NSObject

Comment: I update my title

Comment: Hi kyo. I wonder if I could ask you to refrain from adding your copy+paste block of Markdown text that you are adding to your questions. There's 220 of them at present, and it's unnecessary. Your written question should be tailored to your specific need, rather than copy-pasted into the footer in each case. In this question it was unrelated to your need - you wanted to dump a dictionary in readable form, and so no debugging _per se_ was required.

Comment: Moreover, we ask that chatty and conversational material is removed from posts here. Technical writing is preferred, on the basis that posts are a long-term resource for many readers rather than an ephemeral query to help just the author.

Comment: With this in mind, I often add the following advice to give a better flavour of things that editors will remove: _We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Answer (score 7):

You can use **dump(self)**.

dump() doesn't return a string. It just prints out to the console,

output will be -

```
<SessionAccount: 0x000055957bfcd400> #0
  - super: Foundation.NSObject
  - id: nil
  - username: nil
  - password: nil
  - accountType: nil
  - role: nil
  - privateVlan: nil
  - guestVlan: nil
  - timezoneOffset: nil
  - loginTime: nil
  - cpeName: nil
  - deviceCount: nil
  - activeCount: nil
  - inactiveCount: nil
  - offlineCount: nil
  - quarantineList: 0 elements
```

Answer (score 4):

Is `SessionAccount` really required to be a `class` which inherits from `NSObject`? If you use a struct `print` is going to print all members.

In a `class` you have to override `description` and return a string what you want to display for example

```
override var description : String {
    return "SessionAccount: \(username) - \(accountType)"
}
```